# oauth_signature does not match expected value oAuth Tumblr Request_Token URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, oauth, tumblr

Hello friends I am making login with tumblr using oauth

My problem is I am getting this error in the first step of oauth

oauth_signature does not match expected value

I am using oauth 1.0 library

Here is my first part of code

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  clientID = @"zKJI0u2qC4u9fZzSzDNit289fjYy7zytDevTD0zv1QWzxqSUcb";
  secret = @"P0cJxrFiSPAMHMsLIPTQQf7nGQDDCpDpAP9syWeRhcDrresoyW";

  redirect   = @"http://codegerms.com/";

  [self connectTumblr];

}

-(void)connectTumblr {

```
consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc]initWithKey:clientID secret:nil];


NSURL* requestTokenUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token"];







OAMutableURLRequest* requestTokenRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenUrl consumer:consumer token:nil realm:nil signatureProvider:nil nonce:nil timestamp:@"1416360846"];

OARequestParameter* callbackParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_callback" value:redirect] ;

[requestTokenRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[requestTokenRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:callbackParam]];



OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init] ;

[dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:requestTokenRequest

                         delegate:self

                didFinishSelector:@selector(didReceiveRequestToken:data:)

                  didFailSelector:@selector(didFailOAuth:error:)];
```

}
-(void)didFailOAuth:(NSString*)error
{

}

- (void)didReceiveRequestToken:(OAServiceTicket*)ticket data:(NSData*)data {

  NSString* httpBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  requestToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:httpBody];

  NSURL* authorizeUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize"];

  OAMutableURLRequest* authorizeRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:authorizeUrl

  ```
                                                                      consumer:nil

                                                                         token:nil

                                                                         realm:nil

                                                             signatureProvider:nil];
  ```

  NSString* oauthToken = requestToken.key;

  OARequestParameter* oauthTokenParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_token" value:oauthToken] ;

  [authorizeRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oauthTokenParam]];

  [WebView loadRequest:authorizeRequest];

}

[image: see I also debug the code]

Now how can I solve this problem ?

I am using the same method its working for twitter but not working for Tumblr

Also I manually tried to make the URL but its also not working

https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=zKJI0u2qC4u9fZzSzDNit289fjYy7zytDevTD0zv1QWzxqSUcb&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1

Please help me out :(

I did alot of search but worthable answer found